# How do I debug why unit tests sometimes fail due to Kotlin libs not being available?

Tags: java, maven, kotlin

We have a really annoying issue with some flaky tests: they work 9/10 times, but every now and then they fail with a `ClassNotFoundException` when invoking some Kotlin code:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.collections.Map
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
  at my-project.server.config.KConfigLoader.load(KConfigLoader.kt:77)
  at my-project.server.config.KConfigLoader.load(KConfigLoader.kt:53)
  at my-project.server.config.KConfigLoaderTest.loader_shold_register_unknown_properties(KConfigLoaderTest.kt:65)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.pc.Scheduler$1.run(Scheduler.java:405)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

This happens on our CI server and sometimes locally. What I do not get is the flakyness aspect. Either the Kotlin standard library is on the classpath or not, right? I don't see how it can randomly fail at times.

## Debugging info

### Kotlin related stuff in parent pom

```
 ag -C2 kotlin ../pom.xml 
35:        <kotlin.version>1.5.20</kotlin.version>
36:        <kotlin.compiler.incremental>false</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
37-
38-        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'</maven.build.timestamp.format>
--
47-            </plugin>
48-            <plugin>
49:                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
50:                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
51:                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
52-                <executions>
53-                    <execution>
--
59-                        <configuration>
60-                            <sourceDirs>
61:                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
62-                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
63-                            </sourceDirs>
--
71-                        <configuration>
72-                            <sourceDirs>
73:                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
74-                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
75-                            </sourceDirs>
--
229-            <dependency>
230-                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
231:                <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
232-                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
233-            </dependency>
--
273-            </dependency>
274-            <dependency>
275:                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
276:                <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
277:                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
278-            </dependency>
279-            <dependency>
280:                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
281:                <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
282:                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
283-            </dependency>
284-            <dependency>
285:                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
286:                <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
287:                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
288-            </dependency>
289-            <dependency>
```

#### Plugin config

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${jdk.version}</release>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <!--https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-209-->
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                        <!--Silence class version ignore/deprecation warnings -->
                        <arg>-Xlint:-classfile</arg>
                        <!-- http://jdbi.org/#_compiling_with_parameter_names -->
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Replacing default-compile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Replacing default-testCompile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

### Kotlin related in project pom

Pretty much everything happens in the parent pom wrt setup.

```
369-        <dependency>
370:            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
371:            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
372-        </dependency>
373-        <dependency>
374:            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
375:            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
376-        </dependency>
```

### Output from `dependency:tree`

This is what I get when running  `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=*jetbrains*` in the folder containing the root pom:

```
22:39:55,407 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
22:39:55,542 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
22:39:55,542 [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
22:39:55,542 [INFO] 
22:39:55,547 [INFO] my-project                                                             [pom]
22:39:55,547 [INFO] my-project-commons                                                     [jar]
22:39:55,547 [INFO] my-project-my-app-backend                                              [jar]
22:39:55,547 [INFO] my-project-people-backend                                              [jar]
22:39:55,957 [INFO] 
22:39:55,958 [INFO] ----------------------< no.ACME.my-project:my-project >-----------------------
22:39:55,959 [INFO] Building my-project 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                                     [1/4]
22:39:55,959 [INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
22:39:55,971 [INFO] 
22:39:55,971 [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ my-project ---
22:39:57,889 [INFO] 
22:39:57,891 [INFO] ------------------< no.ACME.my-project:my-project-commons >-------------------
22:39:57,892 [INFO] Building my-project-commons 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                             [2/4]
22:39:57,892 [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
22:39:58,354 [INFO] 
22:39:58,354 [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ my-project-commons ---
22:39:58,385 [INFO] no.ACME.my-project:my-project-commons:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
22:39:58,385 [INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:jar:2.12.2:compile
22:39:58,385 [INFO] |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:jar:1.5.20:compile
22:39:58,385 [INFO] |     \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.5.20:compile
22:39:58,385 [INFO] |        +- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:21.0.1:compile
22:39:58,385 [INFO] |        \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.5.20:compile
22:39:58,385 [INFO] \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:jar:1.5.20:test
22:39:58,385 [INFO]    \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:jar:1.5.20:test
22:39:58,386 [INFO] 
22:39:58,386 [INFO] ---------------< no.ACME.my-project:my-project-my-app-backend >---------------
22:39:58,386 [INFO] Building my-project-my-app-backend 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                      [3/4]
22:39:58,386 [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
22:39:59,524 [INFO] 
22:39:59,525 [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ my-project-my-app-backend ---
22:39:59,568 [INFO] no.ACME.my-project:my-project-my-app-backend:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
22:39:59,568 [INFO] +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.5.20:compile
22:39:59,568 [INFO] |  +- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:21.0.1:compile
22:39:59,569 [INFO] |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.5.20:compile
22:39:59,569 [INFO] \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:jar:1.5.20:compile
22:39:59,569 [INFO] 
22:39:59,569 [INFO] ---------------< no.ACME.my-project:my-project-people-backend >---------------
22:39:59,569 [INFO] Building my-project-people-backend 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                      [4/4]
22:39:59,569 [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
22:39:59,656 [INFO] 
22:39:59,657 [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ my-project-people-backend ---
22:39:59,670 [INFO] no.ACME.my-project:my-project-people-backend:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
22:39:59,671 [INFO] +- no.ACME.my-project:my-project-commons:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
22:39:59,671 [INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:jar:2.12.2:compile
22:39:59,671 [INFO] |     \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:jar:1.5.20:compile
22:39:59,671 [INFO] \- xyz.capybara:clamav-client:jar:2.0.2:compile
22:39:59,671 [INFO]    \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.5.20:compile
22:39:59,671 [INFO]       +- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:21.0.1:compile
22:39:59,671 [INFO]       \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.5.20:compile
22:39:59,671 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
22:39:59,671 [INFO] Reactor Summary for my-project 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
22:39:59,671 [INFO] 
22:39:59,674 [INFO] my-project ............................................. SUCCESS [  1.932 s]
22:39:59,677 [INFO] my-project-commons ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.497 s]
22:39:59,677 [INFO] my-project-my-app-backend .............................. SUCCESS [  1.183 s]
22:39:59,678 [INFO] my-project-people-backend .............................. SUCCESS [  0.102 s]
22:39:59,678 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
22:39:59,678 [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
22:39:59,678 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
22:39:59,679 [INFO] Total time:  4.295 s
22:39:59,681 [INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-14T22:39:59+02:00
22:39:59,686 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Maven version

When this happens, it is usually on TeamCity when running Maven, but we sometimes see it in IntelliJ (not via Maven) as well.

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
```

Comment: Very strange! It happens on multiple machines so it must be something related to the configuration. Can you share more of the log output? What JDK are you targeting and providing? Do you have anything non-standard? Multiple profiles, multi-module, integration tests? Can you check that the the `kotlin-maven-plugin` and `maven-compiler-plugin` are set up like [the example](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/maven.html#compile-kotlin-and-java-sources) to disable the default compiles. Have you tried setting [`kotlin-bom`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-bom)?

Comment: I guess what you mean by log output is the full stack trace? I added the entire stacktrace, so that you can see, but I am afraid there's not all that much more to share. If you know of more details somewhere, I can dig into TeamCity some more to pull it out :) As you can see, we are a multi-module project, implicit by the parent pom, but we only depend on a non-kotlin sibling module. We have multiple profiles as well, but they are not used in that run. From the stacktrace you can see that it is the `surefire` runner, so clean unit test. No, we do not use kotlin-bom. Maybe we should.

Comment: Added a `Plugin config` section and it seems pretty similar to the example config. No default compiles.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. If it's multi-module I wonder if the order of the tests isn't consistent? This might explain the flakiness. The cause might be some modules don't have the correct dependencies... Does `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=*jetbrains*` return inconsistent versions? Can you also share the maven version, and if you're using a wrapper? And is your [Junit + surefire config](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven) up to date? As far as logs - just scour them looking for any warnings or suspect output.

Comment: Added output. No wrapper. We have not updated the surefire config, no ... The order of the tests are most definitely not orderly. We use a parallel runner to speed up the database tests.

Comment: Great! The Kotlin dependencies seem okay. I'd recommend setting up mvnw, but that's unlikely to be cause here… The parallel config is definitely worth looking in. There are lots of results for 'junit surefire parallel noclassdeffoundexception'. Have you gone through posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27225140/4161471)? Does the failure happen when parallel tests are disabled? If not, then try upgrading Junit platform & Surefire (keeping Junit 4) and then enable parallel tests. If it still happens, then you might have to migrate to Junit 5 (which shouldn't be that much work…)